# adding arraylist to another arraylist with different values

Tags: c#, arraylist

I have a dataset with 2 tables, so I declared 2 `ArrayList` and fetching that table values from `DataSet` into two `ArrayList`s.

One `ArrayList` has the count of 66, another of 37.

Now, how do I combine these `ArrayList`s into one `ArrayList` so that I get values of both `ArrayList` into an single `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
array1.AddRange(array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange.aspx) method. But you shouldn’t use `ArrayList`s, they are deprecated. Use the generic `List` class instead.

Furthermore, are you sure you need the separate values at all? Aren’t the data sets enough?

Answer (score 0):

Linq style:

```
IList<int> both = arrlist1.Cast<int>().Concat(arrlist2.Cast<int>()).ToList();
```